# MongoTimeoutException Spark-MongoDB connector Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I tried to use MongoDB-Spark connector documentation examples, however, they do not work. The result is such exception:

```
MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:8081, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
```

The code in my Scala object is:

```
object SparkTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:8081/admin.new_col")
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:8081/admin.new_col")
      .getOrCreate()

    val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext
    sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val writeConfig = WriteConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://localhost:8081/admin.new_col"))

    val documents = sparkContext.parallelize((1 to 10).map(i => Document.parse(s"{test: $i}")))

MongoSpark.save(documents, writeConfig)
  }
}
```

I did not install Kafka and MongoDB but I used their in docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  kafka:
      image: spotify/kafka
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost
  mongo:
      image: mongo
      restart: always
      environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

  mongo-express:
      image: mongo-express
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8081:8081
      environment:
        ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: user
        ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: password
```

What could cause such an exception?

Comment: Could it be that you are forgetting links? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Comment: @stefanobaghino I do not have an application image so which image should link to which image?

Comment: I may be wrong, but don't you need to establish a link between the Kafka and MongoDB containers?